# Laravel echo doesn't listen to private notification callback. Tried everything on the internet

Tags: laravel, echo, pusher, laravel-echo

I've been doing debugging my laravel Echo.

Here is what I have in my `bootstrap.js`. I am not using vue.js and I just using local server `localhost:8000`.

```
import EchoObj from 'laravel-echo';

window.Echo = new EchoObj({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true
});

Echo.private('App.User.'+ loggedUser.id)
.notification((notification) => {
    console.log(notification.type);
    alert("listening")
})
```

My NotificationEvent controller:

```
Class NotificationEvent extends Notification{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database', 'broadcast', 'mail'];
    }

   public function toBroadcast($notifiable){
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            "test" => "nesting"
        ]);
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable){}
    public function toDatabase($notifiable){}
}
```

**Channel.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

I know why my echo is not working because I've checked the pushed debug console whenever I fire an event like `event(new NotificationEvent)` i get this message on pusher

```
{
  "test" : "nesting"
  "id"  : "ecc9912f-0ae2-44dc-b905-677f93bfc38b"
  "type" : "App\\Notifications\\WorkflowUpdateNotification"
}
```

**My public channels are working fine though. What is missing on my private channel.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

For some reason my channel on broadcast was not working for the private channel. so, I had to specify exactly which channel notification to receive. So, I update the `User` Model like this and it worked.

```
 public function receivesBroadcastNotificationsOn()
    {
        return 'App.User.'.$this->id;
    }
```